# How to config mail.php for zimbra mail server in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3, zimbra

I create VPS and install `zimbra mail` in mail.mywebsite.com and  mywebsite.com is in other VPS.

My `mail.php` in `config` folder:

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'mail.mywebsite.com',
'from' => [
    'address' => 'customers@mywebsite.com',
    'name' => 'mywebsite.com'
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'No Encryption'),
'username' => 'info@mywebsite.com',
'password' => '*******',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

In `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

1. I can see `mail.mywebsite.com:7520`.
2. My project is `Laravel 5.3`.

But after send mail, see this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268:
Connection could not be established with host mail.mywebsite.com[Connection timed out #110]
```

Can you fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show .env file configuration

Comment: Hi @BikashP , I update my question :-)

Comment: You should change your email configuration file in .env file first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.env file will look like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp host
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=user_name
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

Comment: Thank you, i update `.env` and don't show any error, But don't receive any mail in my gmail account.

Comment: @mySun gmail have a lot of restrictive rules getting emails from unknown sources and probably is blacklisted.

Comment: Default smtp port is 465 for gmail.